# WD N750 - intermittent

Tags: router, internet-connection

I have recently received a MY NET N750 (Brand new) and after connecting it the internet is disconnecting constantly. It disconnects at minimum once per minute. This is not a short disconnect, but instead a full loss of internet, even web browsing is interrupted. Is the router bad, or is there possibly a configuration problem? Perhaps there is a keep-alive setting which I am not seeing that would improve the connection?

Update: I am currently running my 'MY NET N750' with no issues. Been about an hour of testing. No known configuration changes have been made since the problem previously occurred. So now, the question is why might this have happened and should I worry about the condition of the router? Testing will continue to see if the issue returns.

Comment: Do you have the same problems without the router -- connecting to the modem directly? If so, the problem isn't the router (and this is the most likely situation).

Comment: I have a Linksys WRT54G connected to my modem and it does not have such an issue. I also don't have the issue directly connected to the modem. The Linksys has a similar disconnect problem as of recently, but it is only once or twice a day. The WD literally disconnects every minute.

Comment: You misunderstood. I have two routers, but only one is ever used at a time. The WD N750 is supposed to replace the WRT54G, but, I am failing to get it able. So, I am using the WRT54G until I find a solution or get an RMA (if required) on the WD.

Comment: I'm testing this, however... something odd: So far (5 minutes) my connection has not dropped. Not once. This is with having changed nothing since yesterday.

Comment: What is the difference between 'Warning' 'Notice' and 'Debug' for status? The manual fails to note this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen two different brands of routers do this, but in both cases it was a bad DC adapter that was to blame.  In both cases, you could see the router turn off, turn back on, and cycle up... only to repeat indefinitely.  When the DC adapter was replaced, the problem did not return.

So, when you observe the router during this process, does it actually turn off and turn back on?  Or does it appear to be on the entire time, only to drop the connection once a minute?

If you believe it to be a configuration issue, you could hold the reset button in for 10-15 seconds to return it to the factory settings, and see if the problem happens again.

Comment: It has not lost power at any point since installing it. I can attempt resetting the device, but the configuration should be pretty much default, since this is the first time using it.

Comment: No luck with the restart.

Comment: @Serodis If you need it, here is the manual http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705072.pdf go into the admin control panel for the N750, go to the Admin tab, and look at the log.  If it is not set to log activity, set it to do so.  What does the router log tell you?  HOWEVER, if you have this issue with both the WD and Linksys routers... it looks less like it is an issue with the individual devices.

Comment: Bon Gart, very true comment, but the difference in time between disconnects definitely points at problems with the new router, it literally disconnected once per minute at least. Currently unable to reproduce a disconnect, however. Still continuing testing.

Comment: @Serodis well... then again... go into the router's configuration  sections, go to the last part, the Admin part, and either examine the existing logs, or turn on the logging feature and wait to see what gets logged.  Either way, you need to see what the router thinks and says is happening.

Comment: Bon Gart, can you provide any information on the difference between 'Warning,' 'Notice,' and 'Debug?' So far I am not seeing anything in the logs of value with it set to Notice.

Comment: @Serodis in the context of what things would be contained in a Warning log, a Notice log, and a Debug log... a warning log would most likely contain only things that would be bad or dangerous (DDoS attacks, critical failures)... while a Notice log would contain just about everything (power on, each individual device connection to the router, DHCP assigns, etc)... and a Debug log would probably contain entries with codes (error codes, etc) or information that the hardware developers could use to ferret out potential issues.  **BUT** if the problem went away, there might not be anything to see.

Comment: Well it has yet to come back, I will accept your answer as it may be helpful to people with similar issues. At least the problem has gone away for now.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a WD N750 and found that I could get all router functionality working fine (including printer, storage etc) while the wireless was turned off, but the moment the wireless was activated all connectivity (wired and wireless) to the router became intermittent, including the ability to log into the device, and access to the internet was lost on all connections.

Clients: Windows 7 pro laptop (also part of a domain) and Windows 7 starter laptop , windows mobile phone, with static IP cable.

Played for a few hour including turning off all firewalls on both client and router and turning off all security on the access point, upgraded to latest firmware, all to no avail.  Decided it was probably hardware related so returned and swapped for Linksys E3200 that essentially worked out of the box in the same configuration (needed to set up static IP and turn off MAC cloning).

One has to say the quality of the Linksys interface compared to WD just generally gives more confidence.